# App.focus(iOS Simulator) doesn't work

Tags: automation, simulator, ipa, appium, sikuli

Im currently tring to automate ipa builds with iPhone Simulator. As I use sikuli for my automation, I need the simulator window to be 'on top' for the script to run. But when I use`App.focus(iOS Simulator)` , it doesn't bring the simulator window on top, rather gives an error as 
`[log] App.focus ios simulator(0) #0
[log] openApp: "ios simulator"
[error] App.focus failed: ios simulator not found`

But the same works if I use it to focus either the Terminal or iTunes!
Can you advice as how to proceed..

Answer (score 0):

If I recall right, `App.focus()` takes a string for its parameter. So, it should be `App.focus("iOS Simulator")` (with quotes) Also, sikuli has issues with focusing on minimized windows, so you should make sure it's not minimized...

edit:

I'm noticing too, that your log entry just before says you opened the app. Have you double checked that the proper app is actually opening?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that quotes. 
App.focus("iOS Simulator")
This is what I used to focus, but it din't work for the simulator rather works with terminal and iTunes.

Comment: Ok, here's another suggestion: you could try hovering over the task bar (or mac equivalent) on the iOS simulator, and when the little preview window pops up, see what the title of that window is. Is it 'iOS simulator'? If it is something different, change the App.focus call to however the title of the window appears there.

Comment: I'm afraid this is past what I know. If you can't find answers here, try https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/ --I've had really good luck there.